# What is #defined if a compiler is Cpp0x compliant?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there any official, or inofficial, #defines for when a compiler is Cpp0x compliant?
Even better, for specific Cpp0x functionality (~#cpp0xlambda, #cpp0xrvalue etc)?

(Haven't found anything about this on the net)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Bjarne's C++0x FAQ](http://www2.research.att.com/%7Ebs/C++0xFAQ.html#0x) says:

> ## `__cplusplus`
>
> In C++0x the macro `__cplusplus` will be set to a value that differs from (is greater than) the current `199711L`.

Comment: But the macro `__cplusplus` should not be set to `199711L` for any compiler that does not implement the *full* C++98 standard.

Answer (score 14):

For C++03 according to 16.8/1 (Predeﬁned macro names):

> The name `__cplusplus` is defined to the value 199711L when compiling a C++ translation unit.

For C++0x draft n2857 according to 16.8/1 (Predeﬁned macro names):

> The name `__cplusplus` is deﬁned to the value [tbd] when compiling a C++ translation unit.

Comment: It is reaonable to expect this to be a number > `200911L` but < `201012L`

Comment: No #defines for specific functionality?

Comment: Defines for specific functionality could be defined by implementation. Standard doesn't have such defines.

Comment: @Viktor Sehr: Either a compiler implement the standard or not, there is nothing in-between. __cplusplus may not be set to the predefined value if the full standard isn't implemented.

Comment: `201012L`? You're optimistic. :)

Comment: @Roger Pate: Yup, you win: `201103L` it is. (As with C++98, the value is based on the FDIS date, not the approval date since the value itself has to be approved as well :P )

Answer (score 2):

The official spec includes a value for the `__cplusplus` preprocessor macro, but as others have pointed out, this suggests that *everything* in the spec is implemented. More to the point, no current compiler (that I know of) sets the appropriate value. Specs are well and good, but completely unimplemented bits of any spec should be considered tentative; the intersection of the spec and wide support is the real "standard".

A related question is "how can I tell if at least some C++0x support is enabled?", e.g. with the `-std=c++0x` compiler switch. The answer to that question is compiler-specific and subject to change, but both GCC 4.6 and Clang 2.1 set the preprocessor macro `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` (and give it value `1`) when their partial C++0x support is enabled.