# Determine C++0x availability

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11, preprocessor

I'm trying to determine if C++0x features are available when compiling.  Is there a common preprocessor macro?  I'm using Visual Studio 2010's compiler and Intel's compiler.

Comment: I know this is a duplicate, I just can't find it. EDIT: Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686348/what-is-defined-if-a-compiler-is-cpp0x-compliant

Comment: Thanks GMAN, but that only works if the full standard is implemented (apparently). Intel returns 199711 even if it has lambdas

Comment: Features of C++0x are currently nonstandard.  There is no standard way to indicate the presence of nonstandard features.  If you're looking for individual features, you'll have to roll your own indicators in the build system.

Comment: @Thornley - an excellent point

Answer (score 4):

The macro `__cplusplus` will [have a value](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#0x) greater than `199711L`.

That said, not all compilers will fill this value out. Better to use Roger's solution.

Comment: Do you have a quote from the draft that guarantees that?

Comment: Even with `icc -std=c++0x`, \_\_cplusplus is still defined to 1.

Comment: Nope, just of Bjarne's site. I assume what he said would likely be in the standard,though I suppose that may not be the case.

Comment: Neil: best available is only footnote 149, pg 383, "It is intended that future versions of this standard will replace the value of this macro with a greater value." [n2723]  (Copied identically from the current standard, 16.8.)

Comment: The real issue is compilers don't use the standard value for this macro, either because they "don't have 100% support" or another reason; and it doesn't even apply when you're talking about partial/experimental support of disparate features from a draft.

Comment: I forsee quite  a bit of broken code for people that rely on __cplusplus - not me of course!

Comment: I think g++ currently just `#define`s  `__cplusplus` to 1 due to a compiler bug on some obscure platform.

Answer (score 3):

The usual way to do this is determine it in the build system, and pass "configuration macros", commonly named HAS_*, when compiling.  For example: `compiler -DHAS_LAMBDA source.cpp`.

If you can determine this from compiler version macro, then you can define these macros in a configuration header which checks that; however, you won't be able to do this for anything controlled by a command-line option.  Your build system does know what options you specify, however, and can use that info.

See [boost.config](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/config/doc/html/index.html) for a real example and lots of details about specific compilers, versions, and features.

Answer (score 2):

We've had similar problems with nullptr and auto_ptr. Here's what we're trying to use until somehing is standardized:

```
#include <cstddef>
...

// GCC: compile with -std=c++0x
#if defined(__GNUC__) && ((__GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ >= 6) || (__GNUC__ >= 5))
# define HACK_GCC_ITS_CPP0X 1
#endif

#if defined(nullptr_t) || (__cplusplus > 199711L) || defined(HACK_GCC_ITS_CPP0X)
# include <memory>
  using std::unique_ptr;
# define THE_AUTO_PTR  unique_ptr
#else
# include <memory>
  using std::auto_ptr;
# define THE_AUTO_PTR  auto_ptr
#endif
```

It works well on GCC and Microsoft's Visual Studio. By the way, `nullptr` is a keyword and can't be tested - hence the reason for the `nullptr_t` test.