# C++11 predefined macro

Tags: c++, c++11

Are there any predefined macros for C++ in order the code could identify the standard?

e.g. Currently most compilers puts "array" into "tr1" folder but for C++11 it would be part of STL. So currently

```
#include <tr1/array>
```

but c++11

```
#include <array>
```

What is the predefined macros for 03 standard and 11 standard in order I can use `#ifdef` to identify?

Also, I suppose there are macros for C90 and C99?

Thanksx

Comment: It has little to do with the standard, it completely depends on what your compiler supports.  Any compiler predefines a macro that gives its version number.  Consult your compiler documentation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine C++0x availability](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975616/determine-c0x-availability)

Comment: @Hans Passant: Fail. `The name _ _ cplusplus is defined to the value 201103L when compiling a C++ translation unit.` (16.8 Predefined macro names).

Comment: @phresnel - check out Voo's comment.

Comment: @Hans Passant: "It has tittle to do with the standard" is not correct. Testing for `__cplusplus` _is_ the way the standard sanctions. But I agree with you that you have to work around incomplet and incorrekt implementations of the standard.

Comment: @phresnel - Yup.  And that's why cross-platform libraries like Boost don't use the value of __cplusplus anywhere but are peppered with `_MSC_VER, __GNUC__, __ICC, __MWERKS__`.  Relying on the standard way to check the standard compliance leads to, well, fail as you put it.

Comment: I have solved a similar issue with a bunch of autoconf tests. Of course, that is only good if you are using autotools.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From [Stroustrup's C++11 FAQ](//www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#11)

> In C++11 the macro `__cplusplus` will be set to a value that differs from (is greater than) the current `199711L`.

You can likely test it's value to determine if it's c++0x or not then.

Comment: Note that while this is probably the best you can do, it sadly won't work for VC++ (sigh). The current VC++ (for VS2010) defines `__cplusplus` as 199711L but there's still only `array` no `tr1/array` (but it is defined with a tr1 namespace)

Comment: Hmm not good. Although I guess they were in a difficult position. They couldn't claim to be 0x compliant because they only implemented part of it, and the standard was still a long way off anyway - but wanted to implement the parts they had done in compliance with the standard...

Comment: Note also that GCC fixed it so `__cplusplus` reports something other than `1` (note: not even `199711L`) just a couple weeks ago, so it also won't work for GCC either until 4.7.0 is out. Also, it's not entirely clear from the bug archive whether it'll support something greater than `199711L` off the bat for C++0x builds (though I'm guessing it will).  See http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1773 - a 10+year bug.

Comment: Just looked at the diff for the bugfix - it only adds `199711L` support, so even in GCC you'll need to wait be able to to dectect anything about C++0x using the `__cplusplus` macro.

Comment: in n3242 it is defined as `The name _ _ cplusplus is defined to the value 201103L when compiling a C++ translation unit.`, with a footnote that states that future versions/revisions will increase this number.

Comment: Ok, sounds like this is the correct answer in theory, but it's not too much use in practice until compilers catch up..

Comment: VC12 also defines it as "199711L" which makes it useless.

Answer (score 7):

Nitpick...

Your particular issue does not depend on your compiler, it depends on the Standard Library implementation.

Since you are free to pick a different Standard Library that the one provided by your compiler (for example, trying out libc++ or stlport), no amount of compiler specific information will help you here.

Your best bet is therefore to create a specific header file yourself, in which you will choose either one or the other (depending on a build option).

```
// array.hpp
#ifdef STD_HAS_TR1_ARRAY_HEADER
#include <tr1/array>
#else
#include <array>
#endif
```

You then document the compiler option:

> Passing `-DSTD_HAS_TR1_ARRAY_HEADER` will mean that `std::tr1::array` is defined in `<tr1/array>` instead of the default `<array>`.

And you're done.

Answer (score 7):

From the draft N3242:

```
16.8 Predefined macro names                          [cpp.predefined]
...
   The name _ _ cplusplus is defined to the value 201103L when
   compiling a C++ translation unit. 155)
...
155) It is intended that future versions of this standard will
     replace the value of this macro with a greater value.
     Non-conforming compilers should use a value with at most five 
     decimal digits.
```

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, you're going to have to use compiler-specific information. At least, until C++0x becomes more widespreadly implemented. You basically need to pick driver versions that implement something and test compiler-specific macros on them.

The [Boost.Config](//www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/config/doc/html/index.html) library has a number of macros that can help you.