# What are the C++ 03 Macros?

Tags: c++, c, macros, c++03

I'm trying to compile a library using `-std=c++03`, but compilation is failing because `nullptr_t` is not defined.

How can I guarantee C++03 instead of C++11 compilation using a hard-coded macro?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm kind of confused by what you're asking. `std::nullptr_t` is C++11 and up.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223991/c11-predefined-macro)

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Also, out of curiosity, _why_ are you compiling with `-std=C++03`?

Comment: Mooring Duck: "I'm kind of confused by what you're asking. std::nullptr_t is C++11." - the Boost library is assuming its present when compiling for C++03. Since `-std=c++03` is not sufficient, I'm wondering what macro I should define.

Comment: Mooring Duck: "What compiler are you using?" - VC++ 2008 and above, GCC 4.2.1 and above, Clang 3.1 and above, and Intel and Comeau compilers. The project also supports Android and iOS, so that means embedded Clang++, arm-linux-androideabi-g++ and friends.

Comment: Mooring Duck: "Also, out of curiosity, why are you compiling with -std=C++03" - due to compiler and platform support. Plus, I don't need many of the new C++11 features.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only version detection present in the standard is the value of the macro `__cplusplus`: `201103` for C++11 (ISO/IEC 14882-2011 §16.8/1) and `199711` for C++98 (ISO/IEC 14882-1998 §16.8/1). C++03 didn't apparently deserve its own number and uses `199711` as well (ISO/IEC 14882-2003 §16.8/1). If this seems inadequate to you as a means of feature detection, [you're not alone](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3694.htm).

In any case, you will probably need to consult the documentation of the library in question to determine how to configure it for pre-C++11 if such is even possible.

Comment: Thanks Casey. That explains why I could not find the macro. I would have thought ANSI or POSIX would have defined something....

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I don't know of any macros that work for all compilers. For g++ and clang there is a macro named `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` that is only defined in c++11, so you can do

```
#ifndef __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__
  // Do some c++03 specific code
#endif
```

Comment: `__cplusplus` *should* work in all compilers. The only problem is that it's a bit gray when to change it based on how much C++11 support is there, and that some versions of GCC had it defined as 1 IIRC.

Comment: Technically, the standard says - albeit in a non-normative footnote - that "Non-conforming compilers should use a value with at most five decimal digits." So those versions of GCC may have simply been conforming non-conforming compilers. \*brain explodes\*

Comment: Well, I'm a linux person, and I just tried it with my current version of g++ which returned 1 like you said (for both c++11 and c++03). clang++ works with both macros though. I guess that means for portable code you should do your own define using either the `__cplusplus` or the `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` with some `#define` thingie. Bah. They spend years creating these standards, you'd think they'd give you a standard way of knowing which standard you're using

Comment: g++ 4.8.1 returns 201103 for `-std=c++11`. Interestingly, the clang on Coliru is trunk r184460 and [it returns 201305 with `-std=c++1y`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=fa2ee3a24788a5136063053f32ebd143-9535aeb1525bb8179c73b4851ca159f4). Okay, maybe it's only interesting to me.